# Returning a BlockingCollection as IEnumerable from a method

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

I am trying to return an IEnumerable from a method that is backed by a BlockingCollection. The code pattern is:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Execute() {   
    var results = new BlockingCollection<T>(10);  
    _ExecuteLoad(results);   
    return results.GetConsumingEnumerable(); 
}

private void _ExecuteLoad<T>(BlockingCollection<T> results) {
    var loadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    { 
        //some async code that adds items to results
        results.CompleteAdding();
    });
}

public void Consumer() {
    var count = Execute().Count();
}
```

The problem is the enumerable returned from Execute() is always empty. The examples that I have seen all iterate the BlockingCollection in a Task. That seems like it won't work in this situation.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

---

To make things a little more clear, I am pasted the code that I'm executing to populate the collection. Perhaps there is something that causes the issue in here?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var continuationRowKey = "";
    var continuationParitionKey = "";
    var action = HttpMethod.Get;
    var queryUri = _GetTableQueryUri(tableServiceUri, tableName, query, continuationParitionKey, continuationRowKey, timeout);
    while (true)
    {
        using (var request = GetRequest(queryUri, null, action.Method, azureAccountName, azureAccountKey))
        {
            request.Method = action;
            request.RequestUri = queryUri;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var sendTask = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                using (var response = sendTask.Result)
                {
                    continuationParitionKey = // stuff from headers
                    continuationRowKey = // stuff from headers

                    var streamTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    using (var stream = streamTask.Result)
                    {
                        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "entry" && reader.NamespaceURI == "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
                                {
                                    results.Add(XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement);
                                }
                            }
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (continuationParitionKey == null && continuationRowKey == null)
                break;

            queryUri = _GetTableQueryUri(tableServiceUri, tableName, query, continuationParitionKey, continuationRowKey, timeout);
        }
    }
    results.CompleteAdding();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, but there's not much point calling `...Async()` methods if you're just going to using `Result` straight away.

Comment: Your code original code works fine for me. Have you tried debugging the code in your `Task` to see why it never calls `Add()`? Because that's the most likely explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `results.CompleteAdding()` when you have finished adding items to the collection.

If you don't, the enumeration will never end and `Count()` will never return.

Apart from that, the code you've posted is correct.

Comment: I should have added that. The problem is that method returns right away, and the enumeration is always empty.

Comment: `Count()` will block until the enumeration completes. Have you tried putting a breakpoint on `CompleteAdding()`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turned out that I had an unrelated bug that was causing the CompleteAdding to not get called. Thanks!